# How can I ignore KDE's power-saving features for certain programs?

Tags: kde, power-management, suspend

I want to use KDE Power Saving capabilities on my Desktop computer, such as suspend and screen-off.

But, I want these capabilities be enabled only when some programs aren't running; for instance, I want the screen to remain awake while I am playing a movie with `vlc` or `mplayer`.

For some other programs such as music players (`clementine`), vms (`vmware`), torrents (`ktorrent`), there's no problem turning the screen off, but it is (obviously) not great if the system goes to sleep.

I want to be able to select which programs can suspend KDE's power-saving.

Answer (score 1):

[Caffeine](https://launchpad.net/caffeine) is a great tool that you can control from the KDE system tray. You can manually use it to turn power-saving on or off. An even better function is to list processes that will trigger suspension of power-saving. However, I think that it can only suppress screensavers and suspending together.

Caveat: I haven't used caffeine recently, since it [doesn't support xautolock](https://bugs.launchpad.net/caffeine/+bug/1296666). However, I think the newer versions of caffeine are ["streamlined"](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/05/stop-ubuntu-sleeping-caffeine) (i.e. crippled), and I'm not sure if it's as powerful as previously. I think the old version ([2.5](https://bugs.launchpad.net/caffeine/+bug/1321750/comments/39)) still works, though.

Alternatively, there is [KaffeineTY](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php/KaffeineTY?content=159860), although I've not tried it (I use xautolock, since KDE power-saving is [broken](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=331767) for multiple monitors).